# Series Convergence and Absolute convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the series Convergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}$$

My attempt would be to use the binomial theorem and since the same series raised to n converges to e, then this series converges to

$$\frac{1}{e}$$

Is the series Absolutely Convergent?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ (-1)^n\frac{1}{2^n}\left(4-\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

A part of me says it converges absolutely since the limit of the absolute value of the expression is zero.

Appreciate any guidance

Comment: For the first series, the general term tends toward $1/e \neq 0$, thus the series cannot converge. For the second, absolute value of general term is equivalent to $4/2^n$, whose sum converges, thus your series is absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 2):

The first series is divergent since the general term does not converge to $0$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^{-n}=\frac{1}{e}\neq0$$

The second series is absolutely convergent:
$$|(-1)^n(\frac{1}{2^n})(4-\frac{1}{n})|\leq \frac{4}{2^n}$$
and the geometric series $\sum\frac{1}{2^n}$ is convergent

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. An infinite series $\sum_na_n$ converges *only if* $a_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$.
2. $\left|(-1)^n(\frac{1}{2^n})(4-\frac{1}{n})\right|=(\frac{1}{2^n})(4-\frac{1}{n})<(\frac{1}{2^n})4$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{-n}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}\rlap{\;\;\;\;\;/}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$$